# display current alert when change select value

Tags: javascript

I have a select (dropdown) and an input. When I enter a number at input, select value change with that number:

```
<input id="input" type="text" name="selectChanger">

<select id="select">
  <option value="" selected></option>
  <option value="0">floor 0</option>
  <option value="1">floor 1</option>
  <option value="2">floor 2</option>
</select>
```

I want when change select value, display an alert:

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', function (event){
    let de = new Event('change');
    document.getElementById('select').dispatchEvent(de);
    document.getElementById('select').value = document.getElementById('input').value;
})

document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function (event){
    alert(document.getElementById('select').text + ' was selected.')
})
```

Now when input number 0 , display  `was selected`, and then input number 1 display `floor 0 was selected` but must display `floor 1 was selected`.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

```js
//First Way

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  const target_input  = document.querySelector('#input'),
        target_select = document.querySelector('#select');

  if (target_input != null) {
    target_input.addEventListener('input', event => {
        const { target } = event;

        for (const node of [...target_select.childNodes]) {
            if (node.nodeType == 1) {
                if (node.value == target.value) {
                node.selected = true;
                alert(`${node.textContent} is selected`)
                break;
              }
            }
        
        }
    })
  }
});
// Second way

const {input, select} = {input: document.getElementById('input'), select: document.getElementById('select')};

input.addEventListener('input', function (event){
   const selector = select.querySelector(`option[value="${input.value}"]`);
   if (selector == null) {
        alert('Does not exist!'); 
      return '';
   }
    selector.selected = true;
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
})

select.addEventListener('change', function (event){
    alert(select.value + ' was selected.')
})
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" name="selectChanger">
<select id="select">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="0">floor 0</option>
    <option value="1">floor 1</option>
    <option value="2">floor 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use two `EventListener` .  My real code is very complex and I ask an easy code.

Comment: Your version is not good, you can't do it that way. If you want to use version with 2 events you should do as I edited on the answer

Answer (score 0):

> Now when input number 0 , display  `was selected`, and then input number 1 display `floor 0 was selected` but must display `floor 1 was selected`.

*Slightly confused*, but-

Steps for detecting dropdown value change:

1. Get the element
2. Add an event listener for `change`
3. Detect the selected value

Code:

```js
elem = document.getElementById("select")

elem.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    alert(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].innerText + " was selected")
})
```